# Toggle Switch Losing Styling in HTML Page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to incorporate a toggle switch in my code, but when I do it fails to maintain its styling(ie shape).

Here is the HTML code below:

```
<ul id="switch">
  <li class="on" id="ON"><a href="#">ON</a></li>
  <li class="off" id="OFF"><a href="#">OFF</a></li> 
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#switch{
  list-style:none;
  width:85px;
  height:26px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:90%;
  margin:-13px 0 0 -42px;
}

#switch.li{
  float:left;
  line-height:23px;
  font-size:11px;
  padding:2px 10px 0;     
  background: #E5E5E5;
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F3F3F3),             to(#E5E5E5));
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
  border-left:1px solid #D5D5D5;
  border-top:1px solid #D5D5D5;
  border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset, 0 1px       1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

#switch.li:first-child{
  -webkit-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}

#switch.li:last-child{
  -webkit-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
}

#switch.li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#a1a1a1;
}

.on{
  background: #505050;
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#777),               to(#505050));
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #444, 0 0 7px #9AE658;
  border-right:1px solid #444;
  border-top:1px solid #444;
  border-bottom:1px solid #444;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFF;

}

#switch.li:not(.on):active{
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ddd),               to(#f1f1f1));
}


#switch.li.on a{
  color:#7BBA47;
  cursor: default;
}
```

So instead of having the on and off side by side, the ON label is on top of OFF label. Please help

Answer (score 0):

`li` (list item) elements are block elements by default, and block elements will take up the entire width unless told otherwise. Change their display type to `inline`/`inline-block` to get them in a single line:

```
#switch.li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Working example:

```css
#switch {
  list-style: none;
}
#switch li {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
}
#switch li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #08f;
}
.on {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<ul id="switch">
  <li class="on" id="ON">
    <a href="#">ON</a>
  </li>
  <li class="off" id="OFF">
    <a href="#">OFF</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @dominicbure: I just added a working example to my post. Part of your problem should be that in your original CSS, you have `#switch.li` ("element with id switch and class li"), while you would want `#switch li` ("li element that's a child of element with id switch")

Comment: thank you for the assistance, what is happening is that this is an already functioning on/off switch but once I add it on to my code it then loses its format. I dont know if it is affected by the resources(eg bootstrap cdn), but I have tried using different resources and still have the same problem.

Comment: ok Ive just discovered that the bootsrap CDN is the one that is killing the styling of the switch. How do I overcome this, because I built the page using bootstrap.

Comment: @dominicbure: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with bootstrap whatsoever. I suggest you edit your question (including tags) to encompass this. You could also try to debug it yourself using developer tools, which shouldn't be hard - just disable (meaning overwrite in your stylesheet) anything that doesn't look right (especially `display` changes), and you might quickly find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**dominicbure said:** ok Ive just discovered that the bootsrap CDN is the one that is killing the styling of the switch. How do I overcome this, because I built the page using bootstrap

"You need to override the default bootstrap's CSS with your own CSS document."

Beside that, to fix the on-off button issue you'll need to add this following codes in your on and off classes:

```
/* For On and Off Class */
float: left; 
margin: 3px;
padding: 3px;
```

Hope it works.